# Proof for the following nascent delta function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $f(x)$ be a (nonzero) rapidly decreasing function in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $f(x)$ and all its derivatives go to zero as $x\to\pm\infty$ faster than any negative power of $x$). The sequence of functions
$$
\eta_\epsilon(x)=\frac{\epsilon f(x)}{[\epsilon \pi  f(x)]^2+x^2}
$$
approximates the delta distribution $\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\eta_\epsilon(x)$.

Any idea for proving of this?

It is similar to the well-known example $\frac{\epsilon}{\pi(\epsilon^2+x^2)}$, but not the same.

Comment: Choosing $f=0$ gives a counterexample?

Comment: @Feng Shao: sure, I have edited it to avoid that trivial case.

Comment: You meant $f$ is bounded and it is continuous at $0$ where $f(0) \ne 0$. Show that the sequence converges to $0$ in $L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R}^*)$ thus it suffices to look at a neighborhood of $0$ and show that  $\int_{-r}^r \frac{\epsilon f(x)}{[\epsilon \pi  f(x)]^2+x^2}(C+O(x))dx \to C$ which is easy from what you know about $\frac{\epsilon}{\pi(\epsilon^2+x^2)}$.

Answer (score -2):

Use the practical definition of the Dirac function below:

$$ \delta(x)=\{ \begin{matrix}
 0, & x\ne0\\ \infty, & x=0
\end{matrix}
$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx=1$$

It is straightforward to verify the first condition and it remains to show that

$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \eta_\epsilon(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}I_\epsilon= 1$$

where,

$$I_\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \eta_\epsilon(x)dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon f(x)dx}{[\epsilon \pi  f(x)]^2+x^2}$$

With the variable transformation,

$$ u = \frac{x}{\epsilon \pi  f(x)}$$

The integral $I_\epsilon$ becomes

$$I_\epsilon = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+u^2}
+\epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xf'(x)dx}{[\epsilon \pi  f(x)]^2+x^2}$$

The second integral simply vanishes in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Therefore,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}I_\epsilon=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+u^2}
=\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(u)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=1$$

Thus, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\eta_\epsilon(x)=\delta(x)$ indeed approximates the delta function.

Comment: Do you understand what means "$\eta_\epsilon \to \delta$ in the sense of distributions" ? It means $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \eta_\epsilon(x)\phi(x)dx =\phi(0)$ for all $ \phi \in C^\infty_c$ which you didn't prove. For example $f(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$ then $n^3 f''(nx)+nf(nx) \to \delta''+\delta$ not $\delta$.

Comment: Please be aware: Dirac function is defined as $\delta(x) = 0\>(x\ne 0);\> =\infty \> (x=0)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx=1$. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\phi(x)=\phi(0)$ is a derived property afterwards.

Comment: No you are completely wrong.

Comment: You maybe rushed. Heaviside $H'(x)=\delta(x)$; $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\phi(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)dH(x)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi'(x)H(x)dx =  -\int_0^\infty \phi'(x)dx=\phi(0)$

Comment: If you define $\delta$ as the distributional derivative of $H$ then sure, but it is not what you did, and it doesn't solve the problem of the **convergence in the sense of distributions**

Comment: If you really want to define uniquely a distribution from $f = 0 $ on $\Bbb{R}^*$ and $<f,1>=1$ then you must add that $f$ is of order $0$, that it is a measure, which forbids things like $f = \delta''+\delta$.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.nada.kth.se/~annak/diracdelta.pdf

Comment: Read carefully you'll see that : or they are wrong, or they are assuming they are defining a measure / a distribution of order $0$. Above I gave an example of a sequence satisfying what you wrote in your answer but converging **in the sense of distributions** to $\delta''+\delta$ not $\delta$, what do you want more ?

Comment: No need stuck in purism, rather how Dirac is used in applied fields, such as physics.

Comment: @Quanto. This is a mathematics forum, not a physics forum.

Comment: And this is not purism, if there was a way to make it simpler we would be glad to use it, how do you evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)x^2dx$

Comment: @Quanto: In PDE (an applied and pure field) you also need to use the definition mentioned by reuns in the first comment. It is introduced at the beginning of two modern PDE books - Evans PDE and McOwens PDE which are suitable for a first year graduate student. I wouldn't say that the definition is extremely rigorous - just something that every mathematician would learn. I would review the comments made by reuns. It is okay that you originally didn't know this when you submitted your answer.

Comment: @reuns, would you please give more details about $n^3 f''(nx)+nf(nx) \to \delta''+\delta$? Where $n$ is introduced?